# Rearrage/reorder bargraph with multiple comparisons in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

Considering the dataset below: Three variables alongside a categorical sex variable

```
#Example Data
    Extraversion <- c(4.3, 2, 4.2, 4, 2, 1.5, 3.8, 3.5, 2.1, 2.1, 3)
    Anxiety <- c(1.2, 3, 1, 2.3, 5, 5, 2.3, 2.2, 5, 4.5, 3)
    Depression <- c(2, 3.5, 1, 3.5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4.3, 4.5, 1)
    Sex <- c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
             "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male")
    
    data <- data.frame(Extraversion, Anxiety, Depression, Sex)
```

Now, I realize how I would make a graph like the one from the code here.

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsci)

data %>% #specifies dataset
  pivot_longer(-Sex) %>%  #Pivotes graph longways
  ggbarplot(x = "Sex", #Splitting variable
            y = "value", #Just call this value, its the value on the x axis
            facet.by = "name", #selects variables for comapirson leave "name"
            add = c("mean_se", "jitter"),, #Creates error bars, Adds data points jittered
            width = .99, #Edits wdith of bars
            size = .2, #Border thickness
            error.plot = "errorbar",
            add.params = list(size = .1, alph = .3), #changes size of points and alpha level
            color = "black",
            fill = "Sex", #Fills colors by Sex variable
            alpha = .7, #Alpha for bar fill color
            palette = "jama", #ggsci palette
            position = position_dodge()) +
  theme_classic2() #theme
```

However, I was wondering if there was a way to reorder the comparisons? For example, the comparison for Extraversion before depression and anxiety (from left to right in the graph). At the moment it defaults as Anxiety in the first panel.

I've would typically do something like this with the `forcats` package, but I've only every done it with single variables. Perhaps some way to arrange the panels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the "name" column in a `factor` where your order the `levels` like in the `mutate` in the following code:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsci)
data %>% #specifies dataset
  pivot_longer(-Sex) %>%  #Pivotes graph longways
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("Extraversion", "Depression", "Anxiety"))) %>%
  ggbarplot(x = "Sex", #Splitting variable
            y = "value", #Just call this value, its the value on the x axis
            facet.by = "name", #selects variables for comapirson leave "name"
            add = c("mean_se", "jitter"),, #Creates error bars, Adds data points jittered
            width = .99, #Edits wdith of bars
            size = .2, #Border thickness
            error.plot = "errorbar",
            add.params = list(size = .1, alph = .3), #changes size of points and alpha level
            color = "black",
            fill = "Sex", #Fills colors by Sex variable
            alpha = .7, #Alpha for bar fill color
            palette = "jama", #ggsci palette
            position = position_dodge()) +
  theme_classic2() #theme
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Oh that was much simpler than I was thinking about doing. Lol Thank you very much!